# SQL query to find all homes where everybody is above a certain age

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL to store members of a household. It looks likes this

```
CREATE TABLE housembers (
    id int,
    houseid int,
    housemberid int,
    year_of_birth int
);
```

It has many to one association with the household tables.

Example data might be:

```
1, 1, 1, 1980
2, 1, 2, 1977
3, 2, 1, 1969
4, 3, 1, 1950

Etc...
```

What is the most efficient query to find all the household where all members are over a certain age?

Thanks!

Comment: Or is this not the right way to store my data?

Comment: I rather assume the table name is `housemembers` and the `houseid` contains the "household" identifier.

Comment: Yes. That's right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select houseid
from housemembers
group by houseid
having max(year_of_birth) < date_sub(curdate(), interval @age years);
```

Another method uses `not in`/`not exists` but requires de-duplication:

```
select distinct houseid
from housemembers hm
where not exists (select 1
                  from housemembers hm2
                  where hm2.houseid = hm.houseid and 
                        year_of_birth >= date_sub(curdate(), interval @age years)
                 );
```

This is probably no more efficient than the first version.  But, if you have a `houses` table (one row per `houseid`) and the right indexes, this is should be faster:

```
select houseid
from houses h
where not exists (select 1
                  from housemembers hm2
                  where hm2.houseid = h.houseid and 
                        year_of_birth >= date_sub(curdate(), interval @age years)
                 );
```

Comment: should it be max() instead of min() since you want the youngest to be before before a certain time?

Comment: @TinTran . . .Yes, thank you.  I was thinking about the age when I was writing that.  Date of birth goes in the other direction.

Comment: yeah i wasn't sure either hehe

Comment: Cool solution. Yes, I have a houses table with houseid as unique index.

Comment: The second solution will also return the houseids for which we don't have the birth dates, right?

Comment: @SFO . . . Yes, that is true.